# Importing a json file from a url using node js (express)

Tags: javascript, json, url, express

I'm a node.js beginner. I'm trying to request a json file from a url (i.e 'http://www.example.com/sample_data.json').
My goal is to download/request the file only once when the server loads and then save it on the client side so I can manipulate/change it locally.
I tried

```
var file = request('http//exmaple.com/sample_data.json')
```

but it returns an import module error.
If anyone could give me a start that would be great!
thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To do that i would use the `request` module.

```
var request = require('request');
request('http//exmaple.com/sample_data.json', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
     var importedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
     console.log(importedJSON);
  }
})
```

**For more information about the module check this link:** https://github.com/request/request

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a more complex case (with a proxy and https protocol), and I had to use the `https` module

Answer (score 1):

Just some basics about node, and some first things to try:

1) request is a good choice to use for getting the file, but did you do an npm install? "npm install request --save"

2) in order to use the module, you have to "require" it at the top of your code, like: var request = require('request');

I'd start by checking those things first.